# How to spool three columns from a table and check the summation of the third column in UNIX shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

I have created a query which results three columns. I am able to fetch the details in the spool file and based on that i am checking a condition that the sum of all the values (numerical) from the third column is 0 or not. If not 0, then in the mail the complete result should come.

Issues i am facing are:
1) When i am writing simple SELECT query for the three columns, the results are not coming as three columns and single row for single record. But it is displaying as one row for each column value.

i.e. in TOAD the result is as:

```
   |Column_name_1 |  Column_name_2  |  Column_name_3 |
   +--------------+-----------------+----------------+
   | text_1       |    text_2       |   num_1        |
   | text_3       |    text_4       |   num_2        |
```

But in the spool file, i am getting result as--

```
  |text_1  |
  |text_2  |
  |num_1   |

  | text_3   |
  | text_4   |
  | num_2    |
```

2) The other issue is i am not getting any header in the spool file.

Can anyone please look into this and let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to spool the results to a text file.  Also, please verify that this is not a case of line wrapping in whatever client you are using to view the file.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code. Note that you need (at least) 4 spaces in front of text you want displayed as code ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Code i am using is:     SET RECSEP OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING ON
SET LINESIZE 100
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET TRIMOUT OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET VERIFY OFF

SPOOL $DATA/abc.txt

WHENEVER sqlerror EXIT 1 ROLLBACK;

Select col_1, col_2, col_3
From dual;

SPOOL off



And results are displayed as:

EXCP098
EXCEPTION: Processing not allowed
         2
EXCP014
EXCEPTION: UNKNOWN STATUS
        11

I want the result as:

EXCP098 | EXCEPTION: Processing not allowed | 2
EXCP014 | EXCEPTION: UNKNOWN STATUS       |  11

Answer (score 0):

Try adding SET RECSEP OFF to fix the issue 1, which will solve your problem for record seperation.
Add SET HEADING ON to print the column headers.

See this [link](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html) for a learning.

Comment: Code i am using is: SET RECSEP OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING ON
SET LINESIZE 100
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET TRIMOUT OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET VERIFY OFF

SPOOL $DATA/abc.txt

WHENEVER sqlerror EXIT 1 ROLLBACK;

Select col_1, col_2, col_3
From dual;

SPOOL off



And results are displayed as:

EXCP098
EXCEPTION: Processing not allowed
         2
EXCP014
EXCEPTION: UNKNOWN STATUS
        11

I want the result as:

EXCP098 | EXCEPTION: Processing not allowed | 2
EXCP014 | EXCEPTION: UNKNOWN STATUS       |  11